# Problemas na altura de uma div, como definir altura 'automatica'?

Tags: html, css

vejam o exemplo nesse [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csy3ssvv/11/)

eu quero que a altura da div azul seja de acordo com a altura que a tabela da sua direita está. no fiddle está bem explicativo, qualquer duvida eu tiro nos comentario, tentei de tudo mas não consigo.

```html
<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
  <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block;'> 
    <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>
  
      <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
  <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block;'> 
    <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>
  
      <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
  </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
  <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block;'> 
    <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>
  
      <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div><div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div><div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       <div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div><div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div><div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div><div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div><div style="float:left;">
        <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
          <tr>
            <td>ola</td>
            <td>teste</td>
          </tr>
        </table>  
       </div>
       
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jovem quando for assim tento colocar o código direto na sua pergunta, existem ferramentas destinadas exclusivamente a isso! Evite links externos

Comment: faz sentido, vou fazer isso. Mas achei que não tinha problemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso coloque no Pai `position: relative; padding-left: 150px;` no no Box Azul `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`

Veja funcionando no modelo abaixo

```html
    
    
<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
    <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block;'> 
      <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>
    
        <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
    <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block;'> 
      <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>
    
        <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <br><br>
  
  <div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
    <div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block; 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 150px;'> 
      <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;    
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>
    
        <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         <div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div><div style="float:left;">
          <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
            <tr>
              <td>ola</td>
              <td>teste</td>
            </tr>
          </table>  
         </div>
         
    </div>
  </div>

<div style=' display: inline-block; border-style: solid; border-color: grey; border-width: 2px; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px;'>
<div style='background-color: rgb(245,245,245);  display: inline-block; 
position: relative;
padding-left: 150px;'> 
  <div style='background-color:blue; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float:left;    
  position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;'><span style='color: white;'>a altura desta div tem que ser até o final da ultima tabela</span></div>

    <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div><div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div><div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div><div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div><div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div><div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     <div style="float:left;">
      <table border='1' style='background-color: red;'>
        <tr>
          <td>ola</td>
          <td>teste</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  
     </div>
     
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: você poderia me explicar o porque isso funciona? pois não entendi, mas sei que funcionou

Comment: Julio a primeira parte é colocar postion:relative e uma margin-left no pai, para afastar as tables vermelhas, o margin-left tem a mesma largura que o box-azul. Ai Vc coloca position:absolute no box-azul, como o pai tem position:relative ele vai ficar "preso" dentro do pai e flutuando sem precisar de float. Ai vem os alinhamentos, left:0 para ele desconsiderar a marg-left do pai, depois top:0 para colar no topo do pai, e bottom:0 para também colar no pé do pai. Assim conforme o conteúdo dentro do pai aumenta, o box-azul continua colado nos left, top bottom independente da altura do pai.